# Subscribers in Ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina

How to create two subscribers (subscriber1, subscriber2) for one topic in one Ballerina project?

My approach is as follows :

1. Create init() function
2. initialize two ASBServiceReceiverConfig receiver1 and receiver 2 for each subscriber inside init()
3. Inside public Main function I receive messages for each receiver config which i stored in asb:Message type variables msg1 and msg2
4. Created separate function (function1, function2) for each subscriber (subscriber1, subscriber2) which have the logic to call an other REST API.

Now I exactly can't figure out how to call these functions (function1, function2) inside main using while loop because I need to check if msg is empty or not

```
while true {
do {
    if (msg1 is ()) {
        // 0 messages to read in the topic
        continue;
    } 
    //Call the function which has logic to call an API
    function1(receiver1, msg1);    
} on fail error e{
            // log error here
    }
}
```

This logic will work, if I have Only one subscriber but how can I add subscriber 2 and call function2 inside same project. I can’t add multiple while loops and can’t add function2 in while loop because it is always running for subscriber1's message msg1.

I tried using workers, but it's not calling the API and it closes after reading one message. Is there any way that the thread keeps running?

Answer (score 2):

In the `main` function do you wait for the workers (to complete)? If not, the mentioned behaviour with workers may be observed (see [Waiting for workers](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/waiting-for-workers/) and [Multiple wait](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/multiple-wait/)).

```
public isolated function main() returns error? {
    future<()> f1 = start process(receiver1, function1);
    future<()> f2 = start process(receiver2, function2);
    map<error?> _ = wait {f1, f2}; // wait for the workers
}

isolated function process(asb:MessageReceiver receiver,
        isolated function (asb:MessageReceiver, asb:Message) fn) {
    while true {
        do {
            asb:Message? msg = check receiver->receive();
            if msg is () {
                continue;
            }
            fn(receiver, msg);
        } on fail error e {
            log:printError("receiver failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The example uses `start` actions and futures instead of `worker` declarations ([Named workers and futures](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/named-workers-and-futures/)).

Alternatively, it may also be possible to use the `ballerinax/trigger.asb` module ([Ballerina Central](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/trigger.asb), [API documentation](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerinax/trigger.asb/1.1.2)) that supports asynchronous listener capabilities and avoid the while true loops.

Update: sample code

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/asb;

configurable string connectionString = ?;
configurable string topicName = ?;

configurable string url1 = ?;
configurable string url2 = ?;

final asb:MessageReceiver receiver1 = check new ({
    connectionString,
    entityConfig: {
        subscriptionName: "sub1",
        topicName
    }
});

final asb:MessageReceiver receiver2 = check new ({
    connectionString,
    entityConfig: {
        subscriptionName: "sub2",
        topicName
    }
});

final http:Client h1 = check new (url1);
final http:Client h2 = check new (url2);

public isolated function main() returns error? {
    future<()> f1 = start process(receiver1, function1);
    future<()> f2 = start process(receiver2, function2);
    map<error?> _ = wait {f1, f2}; // wait for the workers
}

isolated function process(asb:MessageReceiver receiver,
        isolated function (asb:MessageReceiver, asb:Message) fn) {
    while true {
        do {
            asb:Message? msg = check receiver->receive();
            if msg is () {
                continue;
            }
            fn(receiver, msg);
        } on fail error e {
            log:printError("receiver failed", e);
        }
    }
}

isolated function function1(asb:MessageReceiver receiver, asb:Message msg) {
    string|http:ClientError resp = h1->post("", msg);
    if resp is string {
        log:printInfo("h1 request successful", response = resp);
        return;
    }
    log:printError("h1 failed", resp);
}

isolated function function2(asb:MessageReceiver receiver, asb:Message msg) {
    string|http:ClientError resp = h2->post("", msg);
    if resp is string {
        log:printInfo("h2 request successful", response = resp);
        return;
    }
    log:printError("h2 failed", resp);
}
```

Comment: Hi @MaryamZi, 
Thank you for the help, I tried with multiple wait but still having issue with that.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this with ballerina modules?

Comment: Are you observing the same behaviour or do you see any errors? Updated the answer with sample code that should ideally work. Would it be possible to check with similar code or update the question with more of what is being done? Please check the suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091819/8887779) using `ballerinax/trigger.asb` too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your use case and the scalability of the solution, an event-driven and asynchronous approach using `ballerinax/trigger.asb` would be a another good approach to achieve your requirement IMO.

You can implement multiple listener services (one for each subscription) which are attached to the same listener and to  the topic, as described in the below sample code.

1. Import the necessary modules.
2. Define the ASB configuration for the project. You can create an `asb:ListenerConfig` for your ASB connection settings.
3. Create an ASB listener instance with the specified configuration.
4. Define a Ballerina service for processing messages from the ASB. You can use the `@asb:ServiceConfig` annotation to configure the service properties like topic name, subscription name, concurrency settings, etc.
5. Inside the service, implement the `onMessage` function to handle incoming messages.

Here's a code sample illustrating the above steps:

```
// Import necessary modules
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/trigger.asb;

// Define the Azure Service Bus (ASB) configuration
asb:ListenerConfig configuration = {
    connectionString: "<YOUR_ASB_CONNECTION_STRING>"
};

// Create an ASB listener instance with the specified configuration
listener asb:Listener asbListener = new (configuration);

// Define an ASB listener service for subscription1
@asb:ServiceConfig {
    topicName: "topic1",
    subscriptionName: "sub1",
    peekLockModeEnabled: true,  // Enable peek-lock mode for message handling
    maxConcurrency: 1,          // Maximum number of concurrent message handlers
    prefetchCount: 10,          // Number of pre-fetched messages
    maxAutoLockRenewDuration: 300  // Maximum duration for automatic lock renewal
}
service asb:MessageService on asbListener {
    isolated remote function onMessage(asb:Message message, asb:Caller caller) returns error? {
        // Handle incoming message logic here
        log:printInfo("Message received from topic: " + message.toBalString());
    }

    isolated remote function onError(asb:ErrorContext context, error 'error) returns error? {
        // Handle error and exception scenarios here
    }
};

// Define another ASB listener service for subscription2
@asb:ServiceConfig {
    topicName: "topic",
    subscriptionName: "sub2",
    peekLockModeEnabled: true,  // Enable peek-lock mode for message handling
    maxConcurrency: 1,          // Maximum number of concurrent message handlers
    prefetchCount: 10,          // Number of pre-fetched messages
    maxAutoLockRenewDuration: 300  // Maximum duration for automatic lock renewal
}
service asb:MessageService on asbListener {
    isolated remote function onMessage(asb:Message message, asb:Caller caller) returns error? {
        // Handle incoming message logic here
        log:printInfo("Message received from topic: " + message.toBalString());
    }

    isolated remote function onError(asb:ErrorContext context, error 'error) returns error? {
        // Handle error and exception scenarios here
    }
};
```

With this setup, your Ballerina project will continuously receive and process messages from both subscribers for the same topic.

If you have any further questions or need clarification on any part of the code, feel free to ask!